# How to Design the Scrollbar in tkinter (not ttk ones)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried to design the tkinter's Scrollbar instead of using ttk ones.

But I couldn't be able to implement designs on the scrollbar. I think I have implemented the same config options as in the effbot docs.

```
from tkinter import *
testing=Tk()
a=Listbox(testing,height=6)
sc=Scrollbar(testing,orient=VERTICAL,command=a.yview)
for i in range(100):
    a.insert(END,i)
a.config(yscrollcommand=sc.set)
def designs():
    # This function does nothing :(
    sc.config(background='orange',borderwidth=34)
    sc.config(highlightthickness=30,highlightcolor='orange',highlightbackground='skyblue')
    sc.config(troughcolor='orange')
designs() # here...
sc.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
a.pack()
testing.mainloop()
```

[image: Here's my output]

is there a way to change the background color of the trough part and non-trough part of the scrollbar and some effects like the active background? Please Help!!!

Comment: This code works for me. I get an orange scrollbar and skyblue highlight-border. What python version are you using?

Comment: python 3.8.3  and os: windows

I have uploaded a pic

Comment: GUI elements in windows (and OSX) are less customizable than in Linux, typically the background cannot be changed, ....  If you want to change the colors of your scrollbar you will have to use a `ttk.Scrollbar` with a theme like 'clam' or 'alt' (or switch to Linux)

Comment: @j_4321 that explains it. Thanks !!! I have used those styles but it is affecting the other scrollbars. that's why I thought to try  ScrollBar().

Comment: I will post an answer then explaining how to avoid affecting the other scrollars (they will be a bit affected due to th etheme change but not by the color change though)

Comment: @j_4321 thanks!! I have tried that but actually, I have other ttk widgets that gets affected by parent change so I will better stick with this default ones :(